# angular2 GMap app is extremely slow, even with zero markers

Tags: angular, google-maps, mean-stack

I have written an angular2 GMap component into a much larger MEAN stack application -- which runs fine, and I only mention it for a more complete picture of the project -- and the GMap itself runs extremly slowly, even with zero markers being created.

The map is initially displayed after a few seconds, which I have so far chalked up to Angular development mode running more slowly than production, but Drag and Zoom user interaction take ten to twenty seconds each to actually re-draw the map, to the point of the map being unusable from the user's point of view.

EDIT: In additional testing, I have noticed the CPU is at 100% while the map is zooming in. I push the "+" button to zoom in, several .png files are requested, the CPU maxes out for several seconds, then the map is finally re-drawn and ready to accept events again. Is this a clue?

EDIT2: If I remove my google API key from the script tag in index.html, zooming is faster and works as expected. Dragging still does not work well enough to be usable:

```
<!--<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKEY"></script>-->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Is this some restriction on my API key? Of course, used this way, the map has an overlay that says "for development purposes only", so removing the key is not the answer. END-EDIT2

EDIT3: Following some different quick start examples, I have modified the code from the original implementation below. Now there is no 'development' overlay, zooming works wonderfully, but dragging is still extremely sluggish:

**index.html:**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY" async defer></script>
```

**googlemap.component.ts:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', this.initMap);
  }

  initMap() {
    const mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(myLAT, myLONG),
      zoom: 7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    this.franchiseeLocationsMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('my-map'), mapOptions);
  }
```

To be honest, I'm not sure what is making the difference here. Is the map now waiting for the DOM to fully load before initializing? That is counter-intuitive to what I would have expected. Do I need to add another listener somewhere to detect map drags and react somehow? Now I'm closer to a solution, but *more* confused by the result! END-EDIT3

Here is the extremely striped down code I'm using. Even in this very basic state, the map is sluggish:

**googlemap.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare const google: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-googlemap',
  templateUrl: './googlemap.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./googlemap.component.css']
})
export class GoogleMapComponent implements OnInit {
  myMap: any;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(myLAT, myLONG),
      zoom: 5,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    this.myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('my-map'), mapOptions);
  }
}
```

**googlemap.component.html**

```
<div id="my-map"></div>
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY"></script>
```

Since this code is so lean and moving around the map is so sluggish, I must be doing something fundamentally wrong. I followed the google maps api documentation and confirmed several examples on the web use this approach. What detail(s) have I gotten wrong?

Comment: The code presented here is fine and there should not be much difference between angular developer mode being enabled or not. Do you have CPU throttling or Network throttling enabled on your browser? Are there multiple instances of the google maps component running at the same time?

Comment: I do not have either of those dev tools enabled. Another possible clue: When I remove my google API key from the <script> tag in index.html, the map of course has an overlay that says "for development purposes only", but now zooming is working much faster and as expected. Dragging is still too slow to be usable. Are there classes of service for certain API keys or something?

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end? I'm having a similar problem